# Has the syntax using SCP changed? Getting unexpected filename error on newer servers

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I have two servers, lets call them SERVER1b and SERVER2.

SERVER1b reaches out to SERVER2 every night to grab my database dumps, they are titled as folows:

```
- dump1.sql.bz2
- dump2.sql.bz2
- dump3.sql.bz2
```

I have a bash script that simply runs the following command:

```
BLOG_ZIP_FILE="dump1.sql.bz2"
BLOG2_ZIP_FILE="dump2.sql.bz2"
BLOG3_ZIP_FILE="dump3.sql.bz2"
scp server2:"$BLOG_ZIP_FILE $BLOG2_ZIP_FILE $BLOG3_ZIP_FILE" /Volume1/Backups/
```

`server2` is an alias used to connect via SSH to the server.

Whats interesting is that I had this script on a previous server, lets call it SERVER1a that has the exact same paths and it worked fine with the only difference being it was a few years older (maybe older version of SCP?)

Whenever I execute the SCP command on SERVER1b I get the following error:

> error: unexpected filename: dump1.sql.bz2

Of course I've double checked the files actually exist, although I don't think that would even be the issue as a different error would be shown.

**Edit: Added verbose dump (the most relevant bit)**

```
Authenticated to host.com ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f dump1.sql.bz2 dump2.sql.bz2 dump3.sql.bz2
Sending file modes: C0664 54580203 dump1.sql.bz2
Sink: C0664 54580203 dump1.sql.bz2
error: unexpected filename: dump1.sql.bz2
```

Comment: did you try to run scp with verbose option to see if any other message is printed ??

Comment: I've just included that now, nothing particularity useful

Comment: what openSSH version do you have ? if you run ssh -v localhost you will get the version

Comment: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2u-fips  20 Dec 2019

Comment: `Server1a` was definitely using something much older, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a fix done in that version to resolve some kind of vulnerabilities. I can't use the option -f in my site, so I can't test it.

Comment: I have a thought what the problem might be, but I'm not sure. Tell me: what happens if you SCP just one file at a time? And -- if that works -- then what happens if you run `scp "server2:$BLOG_ZIP_FILE" "server2:$BLOG2_ZIP_FILE" "server2:$BLOG3_ZIP_FILE" /Volume1/Backups/` (specifying `server2:` for each one)?

Comment: When I only have one file name in the command it actually works fine. As soon as I put more than one file name in there thats when it says the first file name was unexpected.

Comment: (Specifically, I think the problem is that the server-side thinks that `dump1.sql.bz2 dump2.sql.bz2 dump3.sql.bz2` is three files, while the client-side thinks it's just one file with spaces in its name. Until some changes to OpenSSH that were made in 2018, the client-side wouldn't have validated what the server-side was doing, so as long as you liked the server-side behavior, it would have worked fine. But now the client-side is doing validation, and complaining about the mismatch between what it told the server to do and what the server is actually doing.)

Comment: @InvalidSyntax: Note that I asked two things. Could you please try both?

Comment: Hi @ruakh, to answer your second question... this worked :-)

Comment: @ruakh your solution worked, can you turn this into an answer along with your explanation of why this works. Thanks again.

Comment: @InvalidSyntax: Done! (And -- you're welcome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the server-side thinks that `dump1.sql.bz2 dump2.sql.bz2 dump3.sql.bz2` is three files, while the client-side thinks it's just one file with spaces in its name.

Until some security improvements that were made to OpenSSH in 2018, the client-side wouldn't have validated what the server-side was doing, so as long as you liked the server-side behavior, it would have worked fine. But now the client-side is doing validation, and complaining about the mismatch between what it told the server to do and what the server is actually doing. (See https://sintonen.fi/advisories/scp-client-multiple-vulnerabilities.txt for more information about this.)

To fix this, you can pass the three filenames as separate arguments to `scp`, so that both sides will agree about what's supposed to be sent:

```
scp "server2:$BLOG_ZIP_FILE" "server2:$BLOG2_ZIP_FILE" "server2:$BLOG3_ZIP_FILE" /Volume1/Backups/
```

Answer (score 2):

To copy 3 files in a single command, this syntax should work:

```
scp server2:"{$BLOG_ZIP_FILE,$BLOG2_ZIP_FILE,$BLOG3_ZIP_FILE}" /Volume1/Backups/
```

(The server will expand this correctly.)

Comment: I know brace-expansion doesn't work inside double-quotes. But what's important is that it's get expanded on the server correctly.